# Trimming an xpath expression used in a Camel route

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

This might be *either* a camel or an xpath question :).  Note to non-camel folks: camel uses javax.xml.xpath to resolve their xml.

In a camel route, I'm trying to pull an element out of the xml body to use as my filename:

```java
Namespaces ns = getNamespaces();

String fileIDxPath = (see notes);

from("direct:testOutToFile")
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, ns.xpath(fileIDxPath))
    .to("file:/tmp/testing/generatedXML");
```

But I can't seem to get an xpath that gives me the *trimmed value* of the node.  Here's the xpath that I've tried:

```
A) //rm:TradeMsg/rm:Submitter/rm:partyTradeIdentifier/fpml:tradeId/
B) //rm:TradeMsg/rm:Submitter/rm:partyTradeIdentifier/fpml:tradeId/text()
C) //rm:TradeMsg/rm:Submitter/rm:partyTradeIdentifier/fpml:tradeId/text()[normalize-space()]
D) normalize-space(//rm:TradeMsg/rm:Submitter/rm:partyTradeIdentifier/fpml:tradeId/text())
```

- A) Returns the whole node, not just the value
- B) Returns the value, but with loads of whitespace
- C) Also returns the value with all of the whitespace
- D) Throws XPathExpressionException

**Question for xpath gurus** - am I missing something in my xpath that would trim this value?

**Question for camel gurus** - maybe I can trim this value after it's evaluated?  I know I could pass it through another step, but I'd think that this would be a common enough use case to be supported in the ns.xpath call itself.

I also noticed that the ns.xpath sets the header to an instance of 'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList' instead String, which would be the expected type.

Thanks all,
Roy

Answer (score 2):

try this...it works fine in 2.8-SNAPSHOT

```
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, 
           XPathBuilder.xpath("normalize-space(//rm:TradeMsg/rm:Submitter/rm:partyTradeIdentifier/fpml:tradeId/text()", String.class))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
normalize-space(//rm:TradeMsg/rm:Submitter/rm:partyTradeIdentifier/fpml:tradeId)
?

Comment: Thanks Anthony - just tried it, got the XPathExpressionException, like case D.